Poor young man masterfully fakes legal documents?
[Protagonist & Production] I watched this movie something like 9 to 11 years ago on TV, so it's probably a movie from the early-mid 2000's. The protagonist was a white male with something like a dark blonde hair (or something close to DiCaprio's hair). It was clearly not a low-budget or obscure movie, and almost certainly produced in the US.
[Plot] The poor low-to-mid-20's protagonist eventually gets to work on a firm that deals with legal documents with an idea in mind: faking some legal documents to get what he wants. I'm not sure if he fakes them by staying there overnight or if he is shady enough to do his stuff while everyone is working there with him. Probably both, because I remember someone coming up to him while he was handling his shady material or looking for something where he shouldn't be.
The documents he fakes have something to do with passports and airplanes, I think, and he has to do a very skilled work to make them look legit. (It is possible that he is also faking checks or something related with money. He gets more ambitious with the size of the fakery as he goes on.) 
The whole thing takes place in the 20th Century, probably in its first half or something close to it, given the clothes people were wearing. I am not sure whether he becomes rich/successful at the end of the movie, or if he ends up getting caught by government detectives. It is possible that he was becoming very successful right before getting caught, and the movie has a sad ending.
Thanks in advance for the answers, folks. I have been looking for this movie for a long time, and all I get is stuff like The Aviator and The Counterfeiters. :/
[EDIT]: Movie was found, it's Catch Me If You Can, with Tom Hanks and DiCaprio!

It seems a bit too obvious, but your description matches Catch Me if You Can which starts Di Caprio.
He pretends to be a lawyer and a pilot and spends a lot of the film forging cheques.

Pipped! Too slow.

I just found out about this website called "What Is My Movie?", and through some ingenious searching I was able to locate the movie: Catch me If You Can - with none other than Leonardo DiCaprio! Well, thanks for reading my question, guys. I'm watching the trailer right now and I guess I didn't remember the movie as well as I thought I did!

You might want to elaborate in which way it fits the details from your question in order to flesh out this answer a little more.
